# Error while installing Thingsboard on Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 "[main] ERROR o.t.server.queue.kafka.TbKafkaAdmin - Failed to get all topics."

Tags: apache-kafka, thingsboard

I'm trying to make an IoT platform using ThingsBoard. So I'm going to use ThingsBoard using Kafka and PostgreSQL with TimescaleDB. I tried to install ThingsBoard on Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 (AWS) a bunch of times with Thingsboard installation instruction but failed it.

Give a detailed account of the status, I installed it and got a message "ThingsBoard installed successfully!" And I tried to open web UI of ThingsBoard but it didn't work. I ran the command "cat /var/log/thingsboard/thingsboard.log | grep ERROR" to check errors and "ERROR o.t.server.queue.kafka.TbKafkaAdmin - Failed to get all topics." is popped up.
I also checked the Kafka is working properly so I tried to make a topic and it said "Broker is not available." There seemed to be an error in Kafka.

I tried to install it on my computer with same instruction and it works properly (Ubuntu 18.04) but I don't know why it doesn't work on EC2. I am curious as to what the specific issue is. Please advise and thank you for your input.

I followed this sequence to install Kafka, PostgreSQL with TimescaleDB and Thingsboard.
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/?ubuntuThingsboardDatabase=timescale&ubuntuThingsboardQueue=kafka

```
## thingsboard.conf
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dplatform=deb -Dinstall.data_dir=/usr/share/thingsboard/data"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xloggc:/var/log/thingsboard/gc.log -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+UseCondCardMark"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
export LOG_FILENAME=thingsboard.out
export LOADER_PATH=/usr/share/thingsboard/conf,/usr/share/thingsboard/extensions
export SQL_DATA_FOLDER=/usr/share/thingsboard/data/sql

# DB Configuration 
export DATABASE_ENTITIES_TYPE=sql
export DATABASE_TS_TYPE=timescale
export SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
export SPRING_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/thingsboard
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=12345
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE=5
# Specify Interval size for data chunks storage. Please note that this value can be set only once.
export SQL_TIMESCALE_CHUNK_TIME_INTERVAL=604800000
# Number of miliseconds. The current value corresponds to one week.

export TB_QUEUE_TYPE=kafka
export TB_KAFKA_SERVERS=localhost:9092

# Update ThingsBoard memory usage and restrict it to 256MB in /etc/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms256M -Xmx256M"
```

### zookeeper.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Zookeeper server
Documentation=http://zookeeper.apache.org/
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### kafka.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka Server
Documentation=http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html
Requires=zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/server.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: At a guess, you need to configure the broker's advertised listeners correctly: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your previous question, but if thingsboard, postgres, and kafka are all on the same machine, then show the usage of `/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics` to prove that Kafka itself is working. If it is, then the issue is in your Thingsboard configuration. If Kafka is not on the same machine, then you'll need to change `TB_KAFKA_SERVERS=localhost:9092`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I solved it! Thank you for your help. The reason was I used free tier EC2 which has only 1GB RAM. After I saw your answer like check the Kafka works, I made one more instance and installed Kafka to test. Just I didn't know that 1GB RAM wasn't enough to run both Kafka client and broker on the same machine. Sorry that I missed to write down specific EC2 spec. Thank you

Comment: @RobinMoffatt your link was really helpful to understand Kafka. Thank you! I will write the answer myself soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to two guys who advised me I solved this problem.
Basically it was just the reason that Kafka was not working properly cause EC2 free tier instance doesn't have enough memory to run both Kafka client and broker on the same machine.

I made one more instance for Kafka and tried to run Kafka.
It said

```
failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
```

So I checked err.log file and it was using almost 1GB memory.

So If you try to use *Thingsboard using Kafka on Ubuntu EC2 free tier instance* you will have to make another instance for Kafka. And don't forget you change kafka bootstrap server to the IP of EC2 where Kafka is running

Comment: Hey so you managed to solve it by increasing your RAM? I am facing the same issue, but my machine has 4GB...